# Scala: Does Option[Boolean] makes sense?

Tags: json, scala, functional-programming, boolean, scala-option

So an `Option[Int]` or `Option[String]` or for that matter `Option[A]` results in `Some(A)` or `None`, but a `Boolean` is different as it inherently represents dual states (`true`/`false`), does it makes sense to have `Option[Boolean]`? I face this frequently when a `JSON` response should not include the boolean field based on certain business logic.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sure, it's a reasonable representation for a tri-state: True, False, Don't-Know / Don't-Care.

Comment: maybe not performance-optimal (because it's a full-blown class), but why not?
if you need to optimize, you can encode it as a Byte or Int, for example

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Optionality is an orthogonal concern to what type your data is. So yes, `Option[Boolean]` makes just as much sense as say `Option[Int]`.

Let's talk about your particular use case.

---

If the business rule says the field (say) `isPrimeTime` has to be of type `Boolean`, but is optional, then you should model it with an `Option[Boolean]`.

`None` in this context indicates absence of the value, `Some(true)` would mean "present and true", `Some(false)` would mean "present and false". This would also allow you to add defaults in your code like shown below:

```
val isPrimeTime = json.getAs[Option[Boolean]]("isPrimeTime").getOrElse(false)
```

You can employ various `Option` combinators for other common use cases that arise in such settings. (I would let your imagination work on that.)

---

If your domain has a lot of these "tristate" fields, and if the third state indicates some domain-specific idea, something not evident from the context, I'd strongly advise creating your own sum type. Even though you can technically still use `Option[Boolean]`, that may not be good for your sanity. Here is an example.

```
sealed trait SignalValueIndication
case class Specified(value: Boolean) extends SignalValueIndication
case object DontCare extends SignalValueIndication

// Use
val signalValue = signalValueIndication match {
  case Specified(value) => value
  case DontCare => chooseOptimalSignalValueForImpl
}
```

This would seem like this would be a huge wastage, since you're losing the combinators available on `Option`. That's partly right. Partly because since the two types are isomorphic, writing bridges wouldn't be that hard.

```
sealed trait SignalValueIndication {
  // ...
  def toOption: Option[Boolean] = this match {
    case Specified(value) => Some(value)
    case DontCare => None
  }

  def getOrElse(fallback: => Boolean) = this.toOption.getOrElse(fallback)
}

object SignalValueIndication {
  def fromOption(value: Option[Boolean]): SignalValueIndication = {
    value.map(Specified).getOrElse(DontCare)
  }
}
```

This is still significant duplication, and you have to judge on a case-to-case basis whether the added clarity makes up for it.

A similar advice was made by HaskellTips on twitter recently, and a similar discussion ensued. You can find it [here](https://twitter.com/HaskellTips/status/432337300920352769).

---

Sometimes the presence or absence of a field is a decision you can encode into structure of your data. Using `Option` would be wrong in such cases.

Here's an example. Imagine there is a field `differentiator` for which the following two kind of values are allowed.

```
// #1
{ "type": "lov", "value": "somethingFromSomeFixedSet" },

// #2
{ "type": "text", "value": "foo", "translatable": false }
```

Here, assume the `translatable` field is mandatory, but only for `"type": "text".

You could model it with `Option` thus:

```
case class Differentiator(
  _type: DifferentiatorType, 
  value: String, 
  translatable: Option[Boolean]
)
```

However a better way to model that would be:

```
sealed trait Differentiator
case class Lov(value: String) extends Differentiator
case class Text(value: String, translatable: Boolean) extends Differentiator
```

Yaron Minsky's [Effective ML](http://vimeo.com/14313378) talk has a section on this. You may find it helpful. (Although he uses ML to illustrate the points, the talk is quite accessible and applicable to Scala programmers as well).

Answer (score 11):

That is a correct use of `Option[Boolean]`. Suppose I have a running job that will take some time to complete, and I want a value to represent whether the job was a success or not. That suggests a value of type `Option[Boolean]`.

- Until the job is done, I don't know whether it's successful or not, so it has value `None`.
- When the job is done, it either was a success or it wasn't, so it has value `Some(true)` or `Some(false)`.

Comment: Kudos if you can give an example for `Option[Option[Boolean]]`.

Comment: For any `X`, you may wish to use `Option[X]` to indicate whether `X` is available.  Suppose, for instance, you have a subtask for checking whether a job is a success; that subtask reports an `Option[Boolean]` to indicate success/failure/incomplete, and you might return an `Option[Option[Boolean]]` to indicate that the subtask is not responding.  Eventually you might flatten it, but initially you want to respond very differently to a task failing and a task-handler failing.

Comment: @RexKerr I meant it to be humorous. :) But a good explanation nonetheless.